# AWS S3 file recently uploaded not updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I upload a file through AWS Console on S3, and I see there but it's not being updated unless I execute this command on CLI:

```
 aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id E1XXXXXXX --paths "/*"
```

Where `E1XXXXXXX` is the ID from the CloudFront distribution.

I have a user that will not use the CLI, only has access to Console and only S3, so he just can do 2 things:

- upload files to some bucket
- delete files from that bucket

But how can I do in order to get refreshed/updated the file that he is uploading/replacing, without that command on CLI?

Or how can I change the TTL on CloudFront but for an specific Bucket? by default I see a policy with this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a behavior set up that maps your distribution to the S3-origin, you should be able to set your default TTL there. It's the one that will be set for S3-Content.

[image]

---

[image]

---

If that doesn't work, you can attach a Lambda function to the S3 object create event and create an invalidation for changed objects.

Comment: That worked, I put the Default to 0, I hope that 0 doesn't make any problem.

Comment: 0 will stop it from caching at all, essentially invalidation most of the benefits of a CDN, so that's not what I'd choose.